# Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.9.20) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.8.0)

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

can anyone help :
[image]
flutter version : 3.16.9
android sdk : 34
jdk : 11

i tried gradle 7.XX always getting errors
i tried kotlin 1.8.0 also getting same error i think compatibility issues

error : Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.5.1/gradle-8.5.1.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.5.1/gradle-8.5.1.pom
  Required by:
  project :app

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 16s

Answer (score 0):

The `com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.1` package does not exist (at least not yet). The latest stable version is `8.2.2`, the latest alpha version is `8.4.0-alpha09`. You can find all available versions of that package in [Google's Maven Repository index](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=com.android.tools.build#com.android.tools.build:gradle).